# How to Access multi Accesslevel in php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a simple PHP & MySQL college level management system... where all employee and student have own account.. i want to show their own pages
**in my case 3 level admin,teacher,student
 if student login ,or  admin login,teacher login 
how to go own pages  how?? help me please im biggnering ...** 
**my code is**

```
 if(count($_POST)>0) {
$qr = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."' and accessLevel ='".$_POST['role']."'";
    $res = mysql_query($qr) or die($qr);
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
        $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['u_id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    //echo $_SESSION['u_id']; die();
    }
        else {
$message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
}
}
if(isset($_SESSION["u_id"])) {
header("Location: admin_home.php");
}
?>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="input-prepend" title="Username" data-rel="tooltip">
                                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span><input autofocus class="input-large span10" name="username" id="username" type="text" value="admin" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <div class="input-prepend" title="Password" data-rel="tooltip">
                                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span><input class="input-large span10" name="password" id="password" type="password" value="admin123456" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                              <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="selectError3">Plain Select</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                  <select id="selectError3" name="role" id="role">
                                    <option>Admin</option>
                                    <option>Teacher</option>
                                    <option>Student</option>
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            <div class="input-prepend">
                            <label class="remember" for="remember"><input type="checkbox" id="remember" />Remember me</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <p class="center span5">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                            </p>
                        </fieldset>

                    </form>
```

Comment: What does `"help me please im biggnering ... my code is"` even mean?

Comment: I suspect it means "I am a person with English as a second language, who didn't read the guidelines at [help], especially not the page about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/hlpe/mcve), and I am a beginner at coding.  This is my whole program that I want you to debug"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to do an if test on the **role** variable you're getting through POST

so the end if the snippet you sent would look like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["u_id"])) {
 if($_POST['role']=='admin') {
  header("Location: admin_home.php");
 }
 else if($_POST['role']=='teacher') {
  header("Location: teacher_home.php");
 }
 else if($_POST['role']=='student') {
  header("Location: student_home.php");
 }
}
```

assuming you already have student_home.php and teacher_home.php along with admin_home.php of course

Comment: did try but no luck...

Comment: the "role" column in your database must be filled with values like: 'teacher' , 'student' and 'admin' .

To debug, try to echo the $_POST['role'] variable and see if it's recieved correctly

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: role in C:\xampp\htdocs\Code\index.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined index: role in C:\xampp\htdocs\Code\index.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: role in C:\xampp\htdocs\Code\index.php on line 34

Comment: make sure the $_POST['role'] is beeing recieved correctly by echoing it's value.